# WiFi hardware not recognized

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04

```
ASUS Vivobook Model X570UD
Realtek Wireless 8021.ac
OS: Ubuntu 18.04
```

I installed from a USB drive to this system. It has two drives, one SSD (256GB) for Windows and I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on the second drive (1TB Magnetic).

The system boots up fine, but it does not recognize the wireless hardware. The system settings say: No hardware adapter fine.

The wireless adapter works fine under Windows 10.

From a terminal session, if I do:

```
lshw -C network
```

I see a message that the wired adapter is working fine, but on the second block, it shows:

```
Network UNMATCHED
Realtek
.......
```

I sent to he realtek website, but I did not find any drivers. In addition, after I do the lshw command, my mouse pointer disappears.

When I do:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
```

I get:

```
03:00.0 Network Controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b822]
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:2950]
    kernel modules: r8822be
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    softblocked: no
    hardblock: no
```

Note that when I do these commands:

```
lshw -C network
```

or

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
```

The mouse pointer disappears, and I have to power down.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @pilot6 See the edit to my question

Comment: See https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2364383

Comment: And something is wrong with your system. I think the extra kernel module did not install.

Comment: I am reading the thread you pointed me to, but it seems as if the solution is to buy another wireless adapter, either to replace the internal one, or a USB. In the meanwhile, what you do you mean by the extra kernel module did not install?

Comment: This realtek adapter should be supported out of the box in 18.04. It looks wrong that the kernel module is not in use. And the mouse pointer problem also looks wrong.

Comment: I am trying to re-install. When I rebooted from the USB drive (that I used to install), the mouse kept working, when I issued the commands in terminal. I also got a different result: spci -knn | grep Net -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b822]
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:2950]
    Kernel modules: r8822be

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,
I also faced the same problem a few days earlier, follow these steps:

1. Click on the Show Applications icon on the bottom of favorite apps bar (it has an icon of dotted points).
2. Select Software & Updates option.
3. Go to additional drivers tab.
4. It will show your wireless network driver, you have to select to Using [whatever name of the driver is there].
5. Provide permission if it asks for any.

Now check if your wifi option has appeared, if not reboot the system and Voila! your wifi is working.

Comment: The wireless hardware is not found, so there are no drivers available in additional drivers.